# PHP write text from a form on a textfile

Tags: php, forms, get, fopen

I'm making a guestbook program which takes a name and message from different inputs, and there is a third input - mode. If the value of mode is "save", the program writes the senders and messages on a text file as arrays where the characters are divided by a vertical line.

```
<?php 
$sender=$_GET["sender"];
$message=$_GET["message"];
$mode=$_GET["mode"];
$guestbook="guestbook.txt"; 
$fp = @fopen($guestbook, "w"); 

$arr = array($sender, $message);
$text = implode("|",$arr);

if ($mode == "save"){
        fwrite($fp,$text."\n");
}
?>
```

This is my code, but nothing goes to the file if the value of mode is save. Also I am not sure whether I should write a loop if I want the inputs to be filled multiple times and the program to print all the different values on the file, such as

```
Firstsendername|firstmessage 
secondsendername|secondmessage ...
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Get rid of the `@` and use `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');` Also use `a` instead of `w` to append.

Comment: Beware of possible security issues.

Comment: @FirstOne what do you mean by security issues?

Comment: Webserver doesn't have write access to the file or directory.  Error reporting will help narrow it down.

Comment: why do you have a new \n line in the fwrite function?

Comment: do a chown on the directory with chown werbserver-user -R directory/

Comment: I'm really new to PHP so I'm just trying to understand how writing to files works, I think my error is sth simple inside my code but I can't figure out what, also the new line in the fwrite is because I thought this would put every other sender and message on a new line

Comment: It seems like you're attempting to create a simple database to store guestbook text. I would recommend abandoning the txt file method and look into something like Sqlite: http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-php/ You might find that this will solve your problem and be less of a headache when users use special characters and new lines.

Comment: What output do you get after enabling the warnings/errors reporting (error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', '1');)?

Comment: If you are using some distribution of Linux, most of them have publicly writable directory under /tmp/, maybe try to change the path to /tmp/guestbook.txt - this is just for figuring out if its a permission issue

Comment: Either $mode != "save" or there is a permission issue when trying to write to the file.